# What is 'Automatically complete the configuration of a PC after an update or restart' in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

So I have a question. Because my laptop did not automatically log out after shutting down. I turn off the function Automatically complete the configuration of a PC after an update or restart. But because I have turned that off, I want to know what that exactly means? Will it have much effect on the use of my device?

Edit:

Is this the same as Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a pending completion of updates, so Windows will complete updates when you turn on your computer.

It is possible updates completed on shut down, but you will know that when you start up as (a) no updates or (b) updates will complete.

You should not be trying to turn updates off. That does not work.

**Note based on comments:**

There is a setting in Start, Settings, Email and Accounts, Sign in that "Sign in Information may be used to finish setting up device" .

If this is not enabled, updates will simply happen automatically.

I always (and very deliberately) restart after updates to complete all updates, even if minutes later I shut down. I do this to prevent an update issue when I start up next.

The Help on this setting is not informative and just says (as I noted) finish the updates.

[image]

Comment: So it won't work to logout from my when I turn off the laptop?

Comment: When you turn off your laptop, either updates completed then, or will complete when you turn back on. You log out when you turn off.

Comment: My laptop does not automatically log out when I shut down. Because every time I want to shut down my laptop, there is a message that another user is logged in. I have been looking for a solution for a long time. But nothing seems to help. 
I have two users on my laptop. One user is me, and the other user is my brother.

Comment: Check what users you have . An extra administrative user (or you are not the admin) may be running a process that keeps the other user alive. Log in as that other user and close it down. I am assuming this is your own laptop and not the property of a business or school. Please edit your question to clarify if needed.

Comment: Okay I'm going to ask another question and not type everything here in the comment. Thank you.

Comment: Is 'Automatically complete the configuration of a PC after an update or restart' the same as 'Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart.'

Comment: Your own log in should complete any outstanding updates if there are any. I usually restart after updates to complete everything. But if they need to complete (sometimes there is an update process after start up) then you will see a message like this.

Comment: I amended my answer because of the increased clarity. The latter setting  "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device" can be left unchecked (disabled). If not enabled, any necessary setup because of updates will happen automatically ( and may, on occasion, cause another message if necessary to complete things).

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm going to ask someone else a new question if they can come up with another solution. Thank you, have a nice day!