# Users stays logged in when shutdown computer

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

For the past few weeks, my users are still logged in every time I shut down the computer. I tried to disable 'Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart'. But that was not convenient to turn off. Here below is the link to the page where I asked the question. He said that it was not convenient to turn it off. So now I don't really know which solution there is to be able to fix this. Can anyone help?

Link:
[What is 'Automatically complete the configuration of a PC after an update or restart' in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1630255/1280276)

I will explain step by step what my problem is.

We have two users. Let's say we have User A and User B

Step 1: I sign in to User A

Step 2: I shut down my computer

Step 3: Then I startup my computer

Step 4: I sign in to User B

Step 5: I shut down my computer

Step 6: Then a message will popup: "There is a user who is logged in to this device. Are you sure you want to shut down your computer? Any unsaved work will be lost."

I also see this

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgC0Z.png)

Comment: It's not possible for a user to stay logged into a Windows machine when you perform a shutdown.  One of the actions that happens automatically is all users are logged off.  This does not mean that Windows does not have features to make rebooting process faster.  The way you describe your problem does not make sense, it is not clear what your actual problem is, since you indicate the users are not logged off.  **So why have you not implemented the suggested solution from your other question?**  You can [edit] and clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to disable 'Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart'. But that was not convenient to turn off.

This setting is precisely the reason of this behavior. It lets Windows silently log in the most recently used user account on boot. If you choose to log into another account, you now have two accounts logged in and you're seeing the message you've described.

Disable *Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart* as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1262408) to get rid of the prompt. If you'd like to keep it enabled, you have to deal with its direct consequences.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know exactly what you mean. So is it better to keep it on or not? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Bennpoes It depends. When it's on, you'll get faster logins if the last user is returning after a shutdown and shorter wait times after Windows upgrade. The downside is if a different user logs in, they'll get the (misleading) "Someone else is using this computer" message before shutdown. Turning that setting off will remove the message, but returning users won't benefit from being able to reach their desktop slightly faster.

Comment: Very extensive and clearly explained! Thank you very much! But as described here [link](https://superuser.com/q/1630255/1280276), is disabling the feature also bad for the updates? Or have I misunderstood this?

Comment: @Bennpoes Here's the rationale behind this feature. Large Windows updates (released twice a year) require a lenghty setup process on the first login after the update. If you tend to leave the computer on overnight it's quite irritating to find out in the morning that Windows has restarted to install updates, but you still have to wait 10 minutes for it to complete the update process once you enter your password. It had the whole night to do that, why do you have to wait? This feature lets Windows log you in in the background and finish setting things up. There's no other effect on updates.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this function is only useful if you don't want to wait too long after an update (/ restart / shut down) of your computer. And that you can log in to a users faster?

Comment: @Bennpoes Basically yes. Windows will immediately start logging in the last user before they enter their password. That makes the login for the last user slightly faster.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clear explanation! I don't know how to thank you! Thank you so much for answering my question so well! Have a nice day!